# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred apache airflow

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, google-cloud-platform, airflow

Getting cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred while creating an airflow job in Composer of Google Cloud Platform

I tried below two piece of codes, but they didn't work.

1. engine = cx_Oracle.connect('user', 'pass', cx_Oracle.makedsn( 'hostip', 'portnum',None,'service_name'))
2. engine = cx_Oracle.connect('user/pass@hostip:portnum/service_name')

   def get_oracle_engine():

   ```
       oracle_connection_string = 'oracle+cx_oracle://{username}:{password}@{hostname}:{port}/{service_name}'
       oracle_host = 'hostip'
       oracle_port = 'portnum'
       oracle_user = 'user'
       oracle_pw = 'pass'
       oracle_service_name = 'service_name'
       engine = cx_Oracle.connect(oracle_connection_string.format(
           username=oracle_user,
           password=oracle_pw,
           hostname=oracle_host,
           port=oracle_port,
           service_name=oracle_service_name ,
       ))
       return engine

       engine = get_engine()
       logging.info("connected..")
   ```

Environment: Google Cloud Platform - Composer, Airflow, Oracle

It should connect to the Oracle database. Any suggestions??

Comment: Small side comment on terminology: the Easy Connect syntax and your makedsn() call are both using a Service Name, not a SID.  I've no comments on the ORA error since I don't know the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Connection timeout refers to the incapacity of the oracle client to reach `oracle_host`. So be mindful that your oracle server has to be accessible from the composer environment you are using. To test connectivity:

1. load gke cluster by using

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <GKE_Cluster_used_by_Composer> \
   --zone=<Composer_Zone> \
   --project=<PROJECT_ID>
```

2. run a pod for testing oracle server from Composer network:

```
kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 --image=nginx:alpine test
```

3. test connection

```
kubectl exec -ti test sh
/ # nc -zv <oracle_host> <oracle_port>
```

if everything work fine you should get something like this:

```
kubectl exec -ti test sh
/ # nc -zv myorchost.internal.net 53701
myorchost.internal.net (10.0.0.11:53701) open
```